# How to autostart an Apache Spark cluster using Supervisord?

Tags: apache-spark, supervisord

Starting an Apache Spark cluster is usually done through the spark-submit shell scripts provided by the code base. However, the problem is that every time the cluster shuts down and starts again, you need to execute those shell scripts to start the spark cluster.

[Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) is great for managing processes and seems like a good candidate for starting the spark processes automatically after reboot.

However, after starting the master process via

```
command=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java -cp :/path/spark-1.3.0-bin-cdh4/sbin/../conf:/path/spark-1.3.0-bin-cdh4/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.2.0.jar:/path/spark-1.3.0-bin-cdh4/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/path/spark-1.3.0-bin-cdh4/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/path/spark-1.3.0-bin-cdh4/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:etc/hadoop/conf -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dspark.akka.logLifecycleEvents=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip master.mydomain.com --port 7077 --webui-port 18080
```

and the worker process by

```
command=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java -cp :/path/spark-1.3.0-bin-cdh4/sbin/../conf:/path/spark-1.3.0-bin-cdh4/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.2.0.jar:/path/spark-1.3.0-bin-cdh4/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/path/spark-1.3.0-bin-cdh4/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/path/spark-1.3.0-bin-cdh4/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:etc/hadoop/conf -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dspark.akka.logLifecycleEvents=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://master.mydomain.com:7077
```

I end up with the following error after I submit my spark application:

```
15/06/05 17:16:25 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/06/05 17:16:32 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 0
15/06/05 17:16:32 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 1
15/06/05 17:16:32 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 2
15/06/05 17:16:32 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 3
15/06/05 17:16:32 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 4
15/06/05 17:16:32 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 5
15/06/05 17:16:32 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 6
15/06/05 17:16:32 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 7
15/06/05 17:16:32 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 8
15/06/05 17:16:32 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 9
15/06/05 17:16:32 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: Master removed our application: FAILED
15/06/05 17:16:32 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: Master removed our application: FAILED
```

Does anyone know how to manage the spark processes through supervisord?

I'm also open to alternative solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spark master can be run in the foreground by

```
command=/path/spark-1.3.0-bin-cdh4/sbin/../bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip master.mydomain.com --port 7077 --webui-port 18080
```

And the worker

```
command=/path/spark-1.3.0-bin-cdh4/sbin/../bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://master.mydomain.com:7077
```